# Почему может завершаться выполнение кода в Thread?

Tags: java, многопоточность, observer

Я пытаюсь создать новый поток, но код внутри него не срабатывает и не выбрасывает никой ошибки.

```
 new Thread(() -> {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + i);
            }
        }).start();
```

Данный поток я использую когда в Observer срабатывает метод onNext(). Поток обрабатывает полученные данные.
Подскажите, может что-то не делаю. Уже совсем запутался.

Comment: Хм... а попробуйте запустить в консоли и нажать на Ctrl + C, это должно послать сигнал который прервет sleep

Comment: Ну по логике вроде должно работать.Я б попробовал это сделать без лямбда, и в зависимости от результатов капали дальше

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин, пытался и убрать лямбу, но особо результатов это не дало.

Comment: А какие тут данные? Поток секунду стоит, потом заканчивает работу

Comment: @ArtyMorris, на самом деле в данном потоке происходит воспроизведение аудио, но данный поток я переписал для отладки, чтобы посмотреть работает он вообще или нет. В итоге оказалось, что он банально не запускается и ничего не выводит.

Comment: Вывод до слипа сделайте , посмотрите че будет

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин, один раз вывело "Thread 0" и все.

Comment: Так сам блок этого кода вы проверяли, отдельно он работает? Если да , то надо смотреть , че перед ним. Попробуйте с приоритетами поиграть

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин, отдельно он выполняется прекрасно, но когда он вызывается через Observer, то он перестает работать.

Comment: Должна ошибка быть в логе

Comment: @ArtyMorris, прошу прощения, не совсем понимаю о каком логе идет речь?

Comment: А прога завершается или виснет. Мб там переходит после этого к другому потоку на вечное ожидание

Comment: Скиньте весь код

Comment: Если именно хаверщаетсч   значит у вас в каком-то потоке завершение программы происходит, а вам надо присоединить этот поток до завершения

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин, там достаточно большой код, но раз вам так угодно. Вот https://gist.github.com/SaNFeeDep/21f88820694e99413173d835353d6318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Выражаю огромную благодарность [Дмитрию Ерохину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/474759/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%95%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD), [Arty Morris](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/362987/arty-morris).

Код был переписан следующим образом.

```
  Runnable task = () -> {
            System.out.println("Priority thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
            System.out.println("Is daemon: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                System.out.println("Thread " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
```

Данный поток почему-то вызывался как демон поток. Это было проверено с помощью

```
 System.out.println("Is daemon: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
```

Затем, просто "вручную" выставлен тип потока через

```
thread.setDaemon(false);
```

Далее весь код заработал, как нужно.
Опять же выражаю огромную благодарностью всем, кто помог. Спасибо.

Comment: Это хорошо. Строчка e.printStackTrace(); пишет в лог ошибку. Если не знакомы с логами, изучите, без них никак

Comment: Про это я знал. Просто не совсем понял, что Вы имеете ввиду.